# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

I thought that this question is more suitable for MSE, and asked it there. ([Link to the MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375111/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-x-nk)) However, it does not get any answer despite the upvotes. It appears that I might have underestimated its difficulty. Please tell me if it is suitable for MO; ask me to delete it if it is inappropriate.

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb Z^+$ be a set of positive odd numbers. I am asked to prove that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that for any positive integer $k$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^k
$$
converges if $k\in S$ and diverges if $k\notin S$.

I have no idea where to start. In the special case $S=\{1\}$, we can let the sequence $(x_n)$ be
$$
y_1,y_1,-2y^1,y_2,y_2,-2y_2,\ldots,
$$
where $y_n\to 0$ but $y_n$ decreases **very slowly**. However I doubt if this would work for more complicated $S$. Note that $S$ can be infinite.

Any hints?

Comment: From the way you ask, this sounds like a homework question (which as you guessed is discouraged here). I will suggest a hint (which I haven't completely worked out, but I think will work). For each odd number, $2k+1$, here's a suggested way to build a sequence which diverges for that power alone. Find a finite collection of numbers $T_k=\{a_1,\ldots,a_l\}$ such that $\sum_{a\in T_k}a^{2j+1}=0$ for $j=1,\ldots,k-1$ and $\sum_{a\in T_k}a^{2j+1}\ne 0$ for $j\ge k$ (e.g. Prouhet). Then build a sequence by concatenating the block $a_12^{-j},\ldots,a_l2^{-j}$ repeated $2^{(2k+1)j}$ times over.

Comment: This guarantees convergence (to 0) for every odd power below $2k+1$; divergence for $2k+1$ and convergence for everything above. Now find a way to mix these sequences.

Comment: "I am asked to prove..." Who asked you to prove this, and under what circumstances, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I cannot remember exactly. I saw it about a year ago on some website, which I cannot remember. It is NOT my homework.

Comment: So, on some website, you were personally asked to prove this?

Comment: A solution is [here](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/fine-soltopolya.pdf).